# PHP: Extract digits and replacing all occurrences from a string with functions

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, replaceall

I have this string:

```
$string = '[userid=77] has created a new task.
[userid=59] and [userid=66] is are subscribed.
This task is assigned to [accountid=2248]';
```

and I would like to **replace all** `[userid=DIGIT]` with `displayuser(DIGIT)` and all `[accountid=DIGIT]` with `displayaccount(DIGIT)`.

So the string should end up like this:

```
$string = displayuser(77).' has created a new task.
    '.displayuser(59).' and '.displayuser(66).' is are subscribed.
    This task is assigned to '.displayaccount(2248).';
```

What I tried so far which only displays the **first** `[userid=DIGIT]`.

```
$text = "[userid=77] has created a new task. [userid=59] and [userid=66] is are subscribed. This task is assigned to [accountid=28]";
print "Before: ".$text."<br/><br/>";

$matches = array();

// Get [userid=DIGIT]
$found = preg_match('@\[userid[^\]]+\]@', $text, $matches);
print $matches[0]."<br/><br/>";

// Get DIGIT withing [userid=DIGIT]
$found2 = preg_match('!\d+!', $matches[0], $match_id);
echo $match_id[0]."<br/><br/>";

// Replace [userid=DIGIT] with function(DIGIT)
$new = str_replace($matches[0],displayuser($match_id[0]),$text);
```

Comment: Seems you want to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) matching the regex ($pattern) `~\[([a-z]+)=(\d+)\]~` and replacing the texts with the appropriate function calls.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: @h2ooooooo But preg_replace_callback will only get the first occurence or userid or whatever. No?

Comment: Absolutely not. It'll call the callback for each match. Why would it have a limit variable if it only matched one match?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Please see my edit as I have tried to match (each?) [userid=DIGIT], get the digit and replace it with its function. Seems to work but only for the first occurence instead of each. Sorry I'm fairly new with PHP.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp Did so. Not sure how would my newbie try help other users with similar problems

Comment: Again, use preg_replace_callback() and not match as you want to replace content. You need to provide an anonymous function or the name of a function to call. Whatever you return from that function will be returned for all matches in your string.

Comment: @h2ooooooo is it possible I can have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match and capture the digits after `userid` and `accountid` and a [`preg_replace_callback` function](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) that will map the captured values to the necessary strings inside an anonymous callback function passed as the second argument:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('@\[userid=(\d+)]|\[accountid=(\d+)]@', function($m) {
    return !empty($m[1]) ? displayuser($m[1]) : displayaccount($m[2]);
}, $text);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/pynfvO).

The `\[userid=(\d+)]|\[accountid=(\d+)]` pattern will match `[userid=<DIGITS_HERE>]` placing the digits into Group 1 or `[accountid=<DIGITS_HERE>]` placing these digits into Group 2. Using `!empty($m[1])` in the callback, we check if Group 1 matched and if yes, use the `displayuser($m[1])` to get the user name by user ID, else we use `displayaccount($m[2])` to get the account name by account ID.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of preg_replace_callback as suggested by @h2ooooooo I came up with the following of which works perfectly

```
$text = "[userid=77] has created a new task. [userid=59] and [userid=66] is are subscribed. This task is assigned to [accountid=4]";

function displaycontact_cb($matches){
  $found2 = preg_match('!\d+!', $matches[0], $match_id);
  return displayuser($match_id[0]);
}

function displayaccount_cb($matches){
  $found2 = preg_match('!\d+!', $matches[0], $match_id);
  return displaycontact($match_id[0],"account");
}

$text = preg_replace_callback('@\[userid[^\]]+\]@',"displaycontact_cb",$text);
$text = preg_replace_callback('@\[accountid[^\]]+\]@',"displayaccount_cb",$text);

print $text;
```